# Problem with filling array with ints [Arduino]

Tags: c++, arrays, c, arduino

have problem with filling array from Serial.
So basically, first asking for lenght of array, then should input from keyborad all elements. Problem is that it's not waiting to enter values into Serial and just fill with 0. If will type values right away, it will put them into array.

My question is how to force wait from Arduino till i will input values.
Thank You!

```
boolean fill = false;
int sum = 0;
int lengthOfArray;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Set lenght of array : ");
}

void loop() 
{
  if(fill == false)
  {
    if(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      lengthOfArray = Serial.parseInt();
      Serial.println(lengthOfArray);
      int tab[lengthOfArray];

      for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++)
      {
        delay(10);
        Serial.print("Tab[" + String(i) + "] : ");    
        tab[i] = Serial.parseInt();
        Serial.println(tab[i]);
        sum += tab[i];         
      }
      fill = true; 

      Serial.println("Sum = " + String(sum));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not forcing to wait as asked, but you can use [`Serial.setTimeout()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/settimeout/) to extend the timeout.

Comment: recommeded style is `if (!fill)` instead of `if (fill == false)` - `bool` expressions can be evaluated directly (since `fill` is a `bool` variable anyway) in conditions and not further compared to boolean value.

Comment: `int tab[lengthOfArray];` this statement (VLA - variable length array, allocated on the stack dynamically) is not C++ compliant. Although it works in C and some C++ compilers if you want to be C++ idiomatic this should look like: `std::vector<int> tab(lengthOfArray, 0);`. However if this is C-intended then you don't have to.

Comment: Each time you go thru `loop` you start over with a new `tab[]` array. Probably not what you want.  Also, I think we need to let `loop()` return back to the Arduino support code for it to gather characters for Serial read...  Maybe re-think how to collect integers one-by-one each time through the loop, and deposit them in a global array outside of `loop()`. Should check array limits to avoid overrun, too, in this case.  (Q: what if the first integer read happens to be 0?  Trusting user input is always dangerous.)

Comment: Its intended to make all in one loop. Was thinking to fiil array one element per one loop, tho no clue how to make array as global value without knowing length. Also it should not be very aware about wrong inputs, just simply filling array, assuming we provide fixed inputs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you're willing to print all the values at once, not for every value that you type.

You may maintain separate for-loops for reading and then printing

```
      for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++)
      {
        delay(10);
        Serial.print("Tab[" + String(i) + "] : ");    
        tab[i] = Serial.parseInt();
        sum += tab[i];         
      }
      fill = true;
      for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++) 
        Serial.println(tab[i]);

      Serial.println("Sum = " + String(sum));
```